# Game in Tkinter: The player name doesn't get displayed

Tags: python, tkinter, text, get, widget

The program is not being able to display the player's name, that should be captured once the player clicks the "Submit" button.

I could probably do it with the Entry widget but chose the Text one to be able to change the height and width more easily.

What am I doing wrong?

```
# The program will start by explaining the rules, which are:
# The user will be asked random questions.
# For every right answer, a piece of the building will be built.
# 10 pieces will be necessary to finish it.
# if the user provides 3 wrong answers, the game will be over.
# The maximum number of questions will be 13.

from tkinter import *
import tkinter.simpledialog
import tkinter.messagebox


questioner = Tk()

questioner.title(" -- Build the BUILDING! -- ")


# Explanation of rules and choice to begin or quit.
def begin():
    rules_var = tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(" -- Build the BUILDING! -- ", """Game rules: You will be asked random questions, and
if you get more than 3 of them wrong, you will lose. If you are able to answer 10 questions correctly, you win!""")

    building_game = tkinter.messagebox.askyesno(" -- Build the BUILDING -- !", "Do you want to start the game?")

    if not building_game:
        questioner.destroy()
    else:
        second_stage()


# Entering name.
def second_stage():
    name_label = Label(questioner, text="What's your name?", font=('arial', 30, 'bold')).pack()
    name_input = Text(questioner, width=30, height=1, font=('courier', 18))
    name_input.pack()
    getting_input = name_input.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    submit_button = Button(questioner, text="Submit", command=lambda: greeting_user(getting_input)).pack()
    
    
# Being greeted.
def greeting_user(name):
    greeting = Label(questioner, text="Hi" + str(name) + "! The game will start in 5 seconds.")
    greeting.pack()
    # greeting = tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(f"Get ready!", f"Hi {}, the game will start in 5 seconds.")


begin()

questioner.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should call `name_input.get()` inside the callback of `Submit` button, not right after `name_input` is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You incorrectly made the variable in the code. You should get value of the textbox in the function itself. Check this:

```
# The program will start by explaining the rules, which are:
# The user will be asked random questions.
# For every right answer, a piece of the building will be built.
# 10 pieces will be necessary to finish it.
# if the user provides 3 wrong answers, the game will be over.
# The maximum number of questions will be 13.

from tkinter import *
import tkinter.simpledialog
import tkinter.messagebox


questioner = Tk()

questioner.title(" -- Build the BUILDING! -- ")


# Explanation of rules and choice to begin or quit.
def begin():
    rules_var = tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(" -- Build the BUILDING! -- ", """Game rules: You will be asked random questions, and
if you get more than 3 of them wrong, you will lose. If you are able to answer 10 questions correctly, you win!""")

    building_game = tkinter.messagebox.askyesno(" -- Build the BUILDING -- !", "Do you want to start the game?")

    if not building_game:
        questioner.destroy()
    else:
        second_stage()


# Entering name.
def second_stage():
    name_label = Label(questioner, text="What's your name?", font=('arial', 30, 'bold')).pack()
    name_input = Text(questioner, width=30, height=1, font=('courier', 18))
    name_input.pack()
    submit_button = Button(questioner, text="Submit", command=lambda:greeting_user(name_input.get('1.0',END))).pack()
    
    
# Being greeted.
def greeting_user(name):
    greeting = Label(questioner, text="Hi " + str(name) + "! The game will start in 5 seconds.")
    greeting.pack()
    # greeting = tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(f"Get ready!", f"Hi {}, the game will start in 5 seconds.")


begin()

questioner.mainloop()
```

Comment: I was struggling for days wih this bug lol, thank you very much, I really aprecciate it!

Comment: Don't mention it. Take care.